# Do most domestic cats prefer to sleep at arms length of humans?

Tags: cats, behavior

Just wondering what is the average distance that an average cats prefers to sleep from 'the ownser'?

Comment: i do not think this can be answered,but it is a fact cats like to be close to their slaves when they sleep but all cats are different and they change over time too.

Comment: My guess would be a /negative/ distance, if that was physically possible.

Comment: No.  For a very long time three successive alphas chose to sleep up against my  hip.  The current one preferred at my ankles until I rearranged the bedroom, now he sleeps elsewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on many circumstances. There is no universally applicable answer to this question.

**Cat preference** - Some cats like snuggling up for heat. Others don't. Others only do it when it's *really* cold.

**Human sleeping habits** - Humans who often roll/move while sleeping are difficult to sleep next to; cats may prefer to stay at a safe distance so they don't have to move.

**Wanting to be petted** - There are clear times where my cats want or do not want to be petted. Depending on that decision, they choose to lie next to me or slightly further away from me.

Other reasons may still exist. I have listed the ones I actively know of.